# Including Protobuf 3.3.0 as a CMake subdirectory

Tags: cmake, protocol-buffers

Is it possible to include Protobuf [3.3.0] as a sub directory to my CMake project? I do not seem to be able to make it part of my codebase compiling with the rest of my projects.

If I just add it as a sub-directory it compiles fine but I cannot use find_package and point it at the protobuf_DIR because I get the following:

```
set(protobuf_DIR C:/dev/cmake-protobuf-example-sub/cmake-build-debug/protobuf/cmake/cmake)
find_package(protobuf 3.3.0 CONFIG REQUIRED)
```

Gives me:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:5 (find_package):
  Could not find a configuration file for package "protobuf" that is
  compatible with requested version "3.3.0".

  The following configuration files were considered but not accepted:

    C:/dev/cmake-protobuf-example-sub/cmake-build-debug/protobuf/cmake/cmake/protobuf-config.cmake, version: 3.3.0
```

Do I need to compile it priory in order for CMake to accept the protobuf-config?

Thanks

Comment: Even compilation (building) is insufficient: you need to **install** the package before use it with `find_package()`.

Comment: Figured that out and install it by including it as an ExternalProject_add

Comment: Thanks for the comment though

Answer (score 2):

The trick is not to use `find_package`. If you build it as part of your project:

```
add_subdirectory(protobuf)
```

then simply linking against it will do:

```
target_link_libraries(mytarget libprotobuf)
```

But there's a catch: the `PROTOBUF_GENERATE_CPP` function won't be available, so you'll need to do add your own custom command to do this step:

```
add_custom_command(OUTPUT myfile.pb.h myfile.pb.cc
                   COMMAND protoc myfile.proto -I PATH_TO_MYFILE --cpp_out=.)

target_sources(mytarget PRIVATE myfile.pb.h myfile.pb.cc)
```